# Next.js custom javascript not running on it's own page

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to add a custom javascript in my next.js page
but my script seems doesn't load properly.
this is not my full code,
but i hope it can represent my problem.

```js
export default class extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
             <div id="myDiv">
               <p>Inside My Div</p>
              </div>
             <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ 
                    __html: '$(function() {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
         })' 
                }} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

why i can't change style.display like code above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using react it's better to use the api that react provided. There is a method called Ref.

For that it's better to convert the class based component to functional component. Then import **useRef** from **react**
Declare the ref

```
const myRef = useRef()
```

Now assign ref to your div

```
<div ref={myDivRef} id="myDiv">
```

Now in your function access it like bellow

```
myDivRef.current.style.display = 'block'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, react will insert this with innerHTML which means it will inserted as DOM text. Second of all, if you're using Next.js, you should have in mind that on server side, you don't have access to the document object and you should check if it is not undefined.

As a solution, why don't you try putting it in componentDidMount as here you have the document object and you can change the style.

```
componentDidMount() { 
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block"; 
}
```